# Two different classes A and B on their own thread calling a method of the same class instance C

Tags: java, multithreading

So I've got a simple Server class that creates an instance of a Listener class for every connection made to the "server". The Listeners run on their own thread.

I get that there might be a concurrency control problem when invoking methods on the Server class that alter files/variables. But what happens if 2 Listeners try to invoke a method that e.g. only returns some information about the server status? 
Can the same Server instance handle 2 calls at the same time? Or will one of the listeners have to wait till the server is done executing the method of the first caller?

Thanks for any help you guys might be able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is not synchronized, the server can handle the two calls concurrently.

But if they ask for status, this means that the status changes over time. And if it changes over time, then all accesses, read and write, to this status should be done in a synchronized way. Otherwise, the listener threads could see an obsolete value of the status.

So the method should be synchronized, or the status should be an AtomicXxx value, or it should be volatile. The best, and correct solution is hard to give without seeing the code and knowing how the status is read and modified.

Answer (score 1):

For something like that, that I imagine doesnt change that often, I'd consider using a ReadWriteLock - so most of the time you can have multiple threads reading the status concurrently, and only have to block them when you want to update the value.